# Issues with Sandcastle : localization and filename casing

Tags: .net, documentation, localization, sandcastle

I'm using Sandcastle Help File Builder to build the documentation for an open source project, and I'm facing two issues :

- The documentation content is in French. I set the language to French in the SHFB project, but most of the generated text is still in English ("Properties", "Inheritance Hierarchy", "See also"...). I saw that there are a few localized files in the SharedContent folders (which are actually not fully localized), but they allow to translate only a few things, mostly details (feedback, disclaimer, privacy statement and such). **How can I localize the rest of the text ?** Note that I have an English version of Visual Studio 2008 ; could that be an issue ?
- The documentation is generated as HTML and will be hosted on an Linux/Apache server. Unfortunately many filenames generated by Sandcastle have inconsistent casing, so it doesn't work on a Linux server. For instance "Index.html" is not considered the default document by Apache (it should be "index.html"), and the CSS files are not found because of the wrong casing... I could fix the casing manually, but I would have to do it again every time I rebuild the documentation. **Is there a known solution to that issue ?** I guess I'm not the first one to host documentation generated by Sandcastle on a Linux server, but I couldn't find any useful information about that...

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a solution to the language issue :

[Update the language of documentation created by Sandcastle](http://blogs.msdn.com/benoitsarie/archive/2009/03/30/how-to-rapidly-create-a-documentation-for-your-code-with-visual-studio-2008-sdk-sandcastle.aspx)

Now I just have to translate all the reference texts ;)

Regarding the second issue, actually there are only 2 files that need to be renamed (Index.html and styles/Presentation.css need to be renamed to lowercase), so it's not so bad...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the first question.

On the 2nd issue, I faced something similar. I built a tool to unpack the .chm file into constituent files, and then twiddle them, adding trailers, etc. You could do something similar and rather than editing them, rename them.

To unpack I used the code from [this article](http://xtractpro.com/articles/Help-File-Extractor.aspx).

But then I found out that SHFB could product .html files directly, so this unpack step may have been unnecessary.  (I don't know, I never went back and configured SHFB to produce html files)

Once you have unpacked the HTML files, or produced them directly from SHFB, you could even do the batch renaming it in a script - like powershell or javascript/cscript.exe.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about a script to do the renaming... but I still hope to find a better solution ;)